# Fedora 16, python subprocess.Popen from IDE vs from terminal

Tags: python, subprocess, fedora16

So as the title says, I'm having problem starting a new subprocess under Fedora. Now the situation is, I have a main python script from which I start a couple of other python processes using:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['python', '-m', 'first_child.run', 'start'], shell=False)
```

Now this works fine on MacOS, debian and windows. On fedora if I run it from Aptana 3 IDE it also works, the only problem is when i try to run this main scrip from a terminal, where I get:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Do you have any ideea what can be the problem here?

Regards,
Bogdan

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is SELinux, but I wouldn't know exactly what to check.

Comment: Anyway, why aren't you using the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/multiprocessing.html) module?

Comment: To check for SELinux interference, tail `/var/log/audit/audit.log` while running the script.

Comment: Well no ideea what's happening but I just deleted the first_child.egg from site_packages and did another install using python setup.py develop instead of python setup.py install and now it seems to work fine.

Comment: @Bogdan: Than I'd say that there probably was an outdated info in the child or parent egg.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this is something you've already thought of -- but the most common cause of OSError from calls to subprocess is that it cannot find the process

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#exceptions

Are you absolutely certain python is in your path?

I know you're probably going to point out you ran this script from the python executable -- but I thought I'd take a shot that perhaps you specified the full path to python when you ran it from the terminal.

For fun, right before the call to subprocess, you could dump your PATH

```
import os
print os.environ['PATH']
```

Answer (score 1):

It's your current working directory. I don't think the problem is that it can't find python, the problem is that it can't find `first_child.run`.

Try printing `os.getcwd()` before you launch the subprocess, and see if it's different in the terminal vs. in the IDE.

On a side note, it's probably more reliable to use `sys.executable` as the python you use in your subprocess, as opposed to just saying python. For example, `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '-m', 'first_child.run', 'start'], shell=False)`